# How to install Pycharm in Window Subsystem Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In Windows Subsystem Linux, Pycharm can easily be install using `sudo snap install pycharm-professional --classic --edge`, and the installation automatically create desktop shortcut for Pycharm.

Since, I'm using WSL with Desktop Environment via RDP, the installation via `snap` required me to insert these first two lines in the PowerShell for Linux.

```
sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
exec sudo nsenter -t $(pidof systemd) -a su - $LOGNAME
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
```

Hence, Im looking for an installation approach that omit the need to include the first two lines, but, still able to provide the `desktop` shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieve through the following steps.

1.Download the installation file from: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/other.html.

-Here, Im using the `firefox` within the wsl to download the file.

2.In WSL-Ubuntu, the `pycharm-professional-2021.1.3.tar.gz` is visible in the `downloads` folder, once download complete.

[image]

3.Extract the `tar.gz` file using `Archive Manager`

[image]

[image]

4. Unpack the PyCharm distribution archive that you downloaded where you wish to install the program. We will refer to this location as your {installation home}.

[image].

5. To start the application, go to "{installation home}/bin", OR directly open a console, cd into "{installation home}/bin" and type:

   ./pycharm.sh

This will initialize various configuration files in the configuration directory:
~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.1.

6. Once the `Pycharm` start, go to `Tools`- `Create Desktop Entry..`

[image]

7. A `Create Desktop Entry` will pop up. For my case, I left the `Create the entry for all users (....)` remain untick. This is because, I got an error whenever I tick it.

[image]

8. Once click ok on the step 7, the succes button will pop at the bottom right of Pycharm screen.

[image]

9. Exit Pycharm, and a Desktop shortcut should be visible

[image]